# How to add text reference to other listings?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add a comment into the columns when the listings has it. Could anyone please help me?

```
<dl class="listings">
<dt>Apple</dt>
<dd>Delicious</dd>
<dt>Green Apple</dt>
<dd>Love it!</dd>
</dl>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Apple, Orange, Banana</td>
<td>Green Apple, Lemon</td>
</tr>
</table>

$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".listings").find('dt').each(function() {
            var title = $(this).html();
            var comment = $(this).next().html();
            $('table td').filter(":contains('"+title+"')").each(function(){
                $(this).html('<span>'+title+'</span><span>'+comment+'</span>');
            });
        });
    });
```

Expected

```
Apple Delicious, Orange, Banana
Green Apple Love it!, Lemon
```

Result

```
Apple Delicious
Apple Delicious
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following assumes  phrases/words in table that you want to change are all separated with a comma.

Otherwise "Apple" by itself is also found in "Green Apple" and can turn into something like  "Green Apple Delicious Love it!"

Thus have to split all the phrases and do direct equality matches of each one individually

```js
$(".listings").find('dt').each(function() {
  var title = $(this).html();
  var comment = $(this).next().html();

  $('table td').filter(":contains('" + title + "')").html(function(_, currHtml) {
      // break all the phrases into array by splitting at comma
      // and map array to new html strings
      return currHtml.split(',').map(function(phrase){
         // check each phrase/word separately
         phrase = phrase.trim()
         if(phrase===title){
           return '<span>' + title + '</span><span> ' + comment + '</span>'
         }else{
           return phrase;
         }
      // join array back into string
      }).join(', ');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl class="listings">
  <dt>Apple</dt>
  <dd>Delicious</dd>
  <dt>Green Apple</dt>
  <dd>Love it!</dd>
</dl>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Apple, Orange, Banana</td>       
  </tr>
  <tr> 
    <td>Green Apple, Lemon</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on it- You can use `split` to split each`<td>` word with a comma as the deliminator.

Then use `indexOf` to look through the array and see if you have a match from your title and the td word

if so then add your html and put it back the way it was with `join(",")`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".listings").find('dt').each(function() {
    var title = $(this).html();
    var comment = $(this).next().html();
    $('table td').each(function() {
      // split the td text into an array using , a the deliminator
      var split = $(this).text().trim().split(",");
      // indexOf will let us know if the title is in this array
      var index = split.indexOf(title);
      // if its in the array then add the comment
      if (index > -1) {
        // we have a match in this <td>
        split[index] = '<span>' + title + '</span> <span>' + comment + '</span>'
        // put the array back to the way it was with a ,
        $(this).html(split.join(", "));
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl class="listings">
  <dt>Apple</dt>
  <dd>Delicious</dd>
  <dt>Green Apple</dt>
  <dd>Love it!</dd>
</dl>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Apple, Orange, Banana</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Green Apple, Lemon</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```